# Gallery in Django

Tags: django

I have a "Category" model. I want to have it so every time I create a category it creates a directory in my `media` folder. From there I want to be able to upload images to the relevant folders and have a gallery in my category view that loops through every image in said categories directory.

**category.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    {% for image in images %}
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="/media/{{ image }}"> <img src="/media/{{ image }}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" width="304" height="236"/>
          </a>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def category_detail_view(request, slug):
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
        images = os.listdir(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
        context = {
            "images": images,
        }
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
    return render(request, 'main/category_detail.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="category")
    category_description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, default=1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        unique_together = ("category_title", "slug")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_title
```

This code seems to work but only for the `MEDIA_ROOT`. I want to loop through the current category

Comment: In your view, how do you know which category are you trying to show? you need a pk or slug to select the desired Category first

Comment: @gabriel My bad I put the wrong function. I updated my post.

Comment: but are you creating a folder for the category when creating the category itself?

Comment: @gabriel No I'm not. Perhaps you could help me with that

Comment: Ok, It will be useful if you add the code you've made to create a category

Comment: @gabriel Added. Note `category_image` is for the categories main image not for gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's do it in your view

```py
def category_detail_view(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    # Get the absolute path where the category images should be
    category_imgs_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
        settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        category.slug))
    # Check if the path exists, if not, create it
    if not os.path.isdir(category_imgs_path):
        os.mkdir(category_imgs_path)

    images = os.listdir(category_imgs_path)
    context = {
        "images": images,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/category_detail.html', context)
```

Maybe it should be better to create the category images path when de Category itself it's created instead of viewed, You've not published the code where you create de Category instance, so, I've did it in your view, it should work anyway.

Note that I've added the usage of get_object_or_404 django shortcut to avoid the try/except, docs here -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

You should consider filtering the contents listed in `images` to ensure only images are in that variable using `os.walk`,  `glob` or something similar.

Hopes this accomplish your needs, if not, don't hesitate to ask for it.

---

**If you are creating your instance from the Admin interface**

Since you are creating your instance from the admin interface, you can create the path overriding the `save_model` method in your ModelAdmin as follows:

```py
class CategoryAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    (...)
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        category_imgs_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
            settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            obj.slug))
        # Check if the path exists, if not, create it
        if not os.path.isdir(category_imgs_path):
            os.mkdir(category_imgs_path)

        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Thank you. I create my Category with my Category model from the admin panel. I got your code to work however like you said it doesn't create the directory until I visit the page. How do I fix that?